# Symfony2 - Entity being deleted for some reason

Tags: php, symfony

This is kind of related to a previous problem, but something strange is happening.

Ok, I pass my view page an array of all my alert entities, and it displays all the alerts on a single page.

```
{% for alert in alerts %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ alert[0].id }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert[0].alertStatus }}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" data-url="{{ path('NickAlertBundle_delete') }}" onclick="delete_alert( {{ alert[0].id }} )"/>
            <input type="button" value="Show" data-forward="{{ path('NickAlertBundle_show', {id: alert[0].id}) }}" onclick="show_alert( {{ alert[0].id }} )" />
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So that works without problem.  You can see however that to each outputted alert, I give a delete button and a show button.  The delete button deletes the selected alert, and the show button should show the selected alert on its own page.

Now the first thing that happens when a button is pressed is that its javascript onclick function is called.  My delete works perfect. My show_alert seems to have a problem.

So this show_alert looks like

```
function show_alert(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('data-forward'),
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data){

            }else{
                alert("Unknown Error!");
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
}
```

I am pretty sure the problem relates to this line

```
url: $(this).attr('data-forward')
```

That should call my NickAlertBundle_show route,

```
NickAlertBundle_show:
    pattern:  /show-alert/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: NickAlertBundle:Alert:show }
    requirements:
       _method:  GET|POST
       id:  \d+
```

Which in turn should call the show action

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $id = (int)$request->request->get('id');
    }

    $alert = $this->get('alert_bundle.manager.availability')->getSingleAvailability($id);

    return $this->render('NickAlertBundle:Page:show.html.twig', array(
        'alert' => $alert,
        'id' => $id,
    ));
}
```

However, when I click on the show button, it seems to delete my alert (so for some reason it is calling the delete route and action).

Is there anything in my code that would suggest why this is happening?

Delete
Javascript

```
function delete_alert(id){
    var answer = confirm("Confirm delete");
    if (answer){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(data) {
                if(data){
                    var splitdata = data.split(":");
                    if(splitdata[0]=="Deleted"){
                        var id = splitdata[1];
                        alert("Your alert has been deleted");
                        location.reload();
                    }else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("Unknown Error!");
                }
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Please try again!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller
    public function deleteAction(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            $id = (int)$request->request->get('id');
        }

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $alert = $em->getRepository('OntroAlertBundle:Alert')->find($id);

    if (!$alert) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Alert entry was not found');
    }

    $alert->setIsDeleted(true);
    $alert->setAlertStatus('Inactive');
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse('Deleted');
}
```

Route

```
NickAlertBundle_delete:
    pattern:  /view-alerts
    defaults: { _controller: NickAlertBundle:Alert:delete }
    requirements:
       _method:  POST
```

Comment: Let's put the "have you cleared the cache" question out of the way. Have you cleared the cache ?

Comment: Have you tried: Logging to the console the function that you think may be causing the issue to see what the value is: $(this).attr('data-forward') or looking in your network panel when clicking the button to see which URL the request is sent to? Just in case the issue is not the wrong URL being used.

Comment: Cache has been cleared, and when I check it in the console it is definately calling the delete url.  I dont know why it is doing this though, does not make sense.

Comment: Could you add the deleteAction() code? Configuration part...